# SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server

I have following tables:

Table Name : LandParces

```
Blockid,  PNo, Name,             Address
=========================================
32000101  5    Chandana De Silva Colombo
32000101  8    Fernance          Badulla
32000203  4    Sunil Fernando    Tangalle
```

Table Name = Owner

```
Blockid,  PNo,  StorP   Hec
===============================
32000101  5     St      0.5020   
32000101  8     Pr      2.1045
32000203  4     Pr      0.1824
```

Table Name = Encumbrances

```
Blockid,      PNo,  Encumbrance
===============================
32000101     5      Life
32000101     5      Mortgage
32000101     5      access
32000101     8      Life
32000101     8      access
32000203     4      access road
```

Now I want to get the result as follows

```
Blockid, PNo, Name,          Address, Encumbrance           StorP   Hec           
==========================================================================
32000101 5    Chandana...    Colombo  Life,Mortgage,access  St      0.5020
32000101 8    Fernance       Badulla  Life,access           Pr      2.1045
32000203 4    Sunil Fernando Tangalle accessroad            Pr      0.1824
```

Pl tell me the T sql server code for this query. Pl help me

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you :)

```
select  LandParces.Blockid,LandParces.PNo,LandParces.Name,LandParces.Address,Encumbrances.Encumbrance
    ,Owner.StorP,Owner.Hec
    from  LandParces 
    inner join Encumbrances 
    inner join Owner
on dbo.Owner.Blockid = Encumbrances.Blockid
 on LandParces.Blockid =Encumbrances.Blockid
```

you can try this other [joins](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) also .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how to join tables together [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1667).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select  LandParces.Blockid,LandParces.PNo,LandParces.Name,LandParces.Address, 
(
 SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Blockid) > 1 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END + Encumbrance
FROM    Encumbrances qi
        WHERE   qi.Blockid=  LandParces.Blockid 
        FOR XML PATH('')
)
 as Encumbrance,Owner.StorP,Owner.Hec
    from  LandParces 
    inner join Owner
on LandParces.Blockid =Owner.Blockid
```

This query is for sqlserver 2005+